# How to keepdims when I use GlobalAveragePooling2D in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

When I use `GlobalAveragePooling2D`  as a weight to multiple another intermediate result from a conv_layer like SENet in `Keras`.
**An Error occurs**: 4D array shape[samples, height, width, channels] convert to a 2D array shape[samples, channels], so when perform the ops 4D multiple 2D it leads to an error on dims not match.
**My Question**: My solution is to use `reshape ops` but I do not know whether it will have an effect on backpropagation, and I want to know is there other solutions or `params` like `keepdims=True` to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write your own version through the `Lambda` layer. Here is the one:

```
MyGlobalAverage2D = Lambda(lambda: t4d: K.mean(t4d, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True), name='GlobalAverage2D' )
```